# VBA - MariaDB - Query cannot be updated because it contains no searchable columns to use as a key

Tags: sql, database, vba, vb6, mariadb

I am using MariaDB and VBA to read/write a flat database using ADODB. This is not by choice however I've been asked to make it work in this manner. An alternative would be to directly use SQL queries however this is a port of a very old VB3 application.

Here is my code that connects to the database, pulls back all records, updates the last record, then calls update to effectively write it back to the database

```
Global DB As New ADODB.Connection
Global TD As New ADODB.Recordset

DB.Open "Driver={MariaDB ODBC 2.0 Driver};Server=localhost;UID=???;PWD=???;DB=sf_log;Port=3306"
Dim query As String: query = "SELECT * FROM `" & TableName & "` ORDER BY `Record ID`"

TD.CursorLocation = adUseServer
TD.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
TD.Open query, DB, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
TD.MoveLast

Dim TestColumnField as string
TestColumnField = TD.Fields("TestColumn")  'This returns the correct value from the database indicating the connection was successful

TD.Fields("TestColumn") = "test"

TD.UpdateBatch (adAffectCurrent)  ' This line throws the error
```

Error that is reported is "Query cannot be updated because it contains no searchable columns to use as a key"

The database is a flat relationship-less database with no keys. I have tried setting "record id" to be a primary key with no luck.

Is this error due to MariaDB not implementing/supporting ADODB recorset? Is it due to my database structure? Or is it simply I am utilising the ADODB recorset incorrectly?

Edit: Here is an example that shows you do not need an SQL update statement. You can simply select the data and call Update.

http://www.accessallinone.com/updating-adding-and-deleting-records-in-a-recordset/

```
Sub ADODBUpdating()
Dim sql As String
Dim rs As adodb.Recordset

sql = "SELECT * FROM tblTeachers WHERE TeacherID=5"

Set rs = New adodb.Recordset
rs.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
'Open RecordSet

With rs
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        .MoveLast

        If .Supports(adUpdate) Then

            ![FirstName] = "x" & ![FirstName]

            .Update            
        End If
    End If

    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Does it work correctly if you set the Connection/Recordset cursor location to `adUseClient` instead of `adUserServer`?

Comment: It is horribly slow (expected, as it pulls the entire database back using the existing queries in the program) however it does work. I will go with this approach and optimise the queries to only return the useful data. If you make this an answer I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: The positive side is there'll be less work if the app will have to be ported to ADO.NET in the future. ;)

Comment: It is written in VBA for some ancient SCADA system unfortunately. If I had to do from scratch I would write it as a standalone .NET application and throw ADODB in the bin and just use entity framework as the database is tiny (it is basically a flat file) so no real care about overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side cursor implementation seems to be limited, use client side cursors (`DB.CursorLocation = adUseClient`) instead.

Answer (score -1):

1.) You can't do an update in SQL with a SELECT-Statement. Instead use the UPDATE-Statement.
2.) Dont't try to update all the records. Only Update the single row you want to update. As you write this should be the last record.

You update the testfield and you have to be sufficiently specific in the WHERE-Clause, that you only select the one and only record record you want to update.

Comment: I thought the SQL statement was simply to get the data in the first place. Do I need to connect again with an update statement once I've modified the recordset?

Comment: http://www.accessallinone.com/updating-adding-and-deleting-records-in-a-recordset/   In this example you can update a record using an SQL SELECT only command. The ADODB recordset must automatically build the SQL update statement. Why does this example work but mine does not? I would rather not rewrite the entire program which previously only uses select statements and calls update. I edited to show an example of this.

Comment: Even if I use a SELECT where and select only one record, it still gives me the same error. I believe the error is not the select statement but something else.